# d3 bound metadata vs closure accessor

Tags: d3.js

in d3, you typically want to render some **data**, e.g. (x,y) pairs:

```
var points = [{x:1, y:2}, {x:3, y:4}]
```

and you have some **metadata** about the rendering, e.g. its width.

```
var width = 100
```

the question is, **where to put the metadata?**

1: use a **closure accessor,** as suggested in mbostock's reusable charts: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

```
selection.data(points).call(thing().width(width))
```

2: use **bound data,** just like everything else:

```
selection.data([{width: width, points: points}]).call(thing())
```

**is there a reason to choose one over the other?**

the closure accessor method seems to involve more boilerplate.

eh?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the closure accessor is more flexible. In particular, if you bind it to the data you have to handle it separately in the rest of the code -- in `thing()` you would need to extract `points` and pass them to another `data()` call to bind them and append elements for each (or whatever you want to do).

I'm always using the closure accessor.